# rxjs 6 Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

Just moved from rxjs 5/angular 5 to rxjs 6/ angular 6, went through this [migration-guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md). Can't seem to figure out what it should be now, any help appreciated.

```js
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
[ts] 'of' is declared but its value is never read.

// trivial example of what im trying to replace
  isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return Observable.of(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can now just import `of` from `rxjs`. So....

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

// trivial example of what im trying to replace
  isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return of(true);
  }
```

Comment: updated the question with the imports that I have, still not working and the linter gives an error. any ideas?

Comment: It's good that you're importing, but `of` isn't an attribute, it's a function that returns an observable. Hence my sample above! 

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSolati, very handy.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Angular 6 /7 or 9

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

And then instead of calling

```
Observable.of(res);
```

just use

```
of(res);
```